# Typeset an upright ell

Tags: math-mode, symbols, italic

The `$\ell$` character in math-mode is clearly slanted to match the usual slant of math-mode characters. Is there a way to typeset an upright version, that won't look slanted amid other upright-math-mode characters?

Comment: Why do you need such a char? `\ell` is after all just a way of making `l` 'show up' more.

Comment: `\ell` is a nice symbol, I prefer it especially in math mode or in diagrams to differ from `I`, `1` or `l`. I also wonder why you want to make it 'upright'?

Comment: Since `\ell` denotes the character SCRIPT SMALL L, which is derived from an italic l (as the Unicode Standard says), it is in essence italic. It is illogical to try to make it upright.

Comment: For those asking why I want such a thing, I typeset scalar quantities in italic, and vector quantities in upright bold. `\boldsymbol\ell` suffices to make `\ell` boldface, but it is still italic. I wanted to know how to make it upright as well. `\mathbf{l}` is unsatisfactory to me because it is confusable with a 1 even more so upright than italicized.

Comment: You have an upright ell in the `Minion Pro Regular` text font (U2113). I suppose you could declare this character as a math symbol.

Comment: Another possible reason: the `\ell` in $\ell^p$-space is a constant, and ‘should’ therefore be set upright (as far as I know nobody does this, however).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I defined a new control sequence `\uell` which typesets an `\ell` but rotated by 10 degrees. It also adjusts the spacing around the rotated `\ell` to be the same as for unrotated `\ell`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\uell{\mathpalette\@uell\relax}
\newcommand*\@uell[2]{
  % We need to adjust the width of \uell to be the same as \ell
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\ell$}
  \setbox1=\hbox{\rotatebox{10}{$#1\ell$}}
  \dimen0=\wd0 \advance\dimen0 by -\wd1 \divide\dimen0 by 2
  \mathord{\lower 0.1ex \hbox{\kern\dimen0\unhbox1\kern\dimen0}}
}
\begin{document}
\section{$\uell$}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \string\ell  & $jk\ell mn$                  \\
  \string\uell & $jk\uell mn$                 \\
  \string\ell  & $jk\ell_{\ell_{\ell}} mn$    \\
  \string\uell & $jk\uell_{\uell_{\uell}} mn$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## Using `expl3`

The output stays the same, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
%\usepackage{xparse} expl3 is now default since 2020
\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l_uell_box
\dim_new:N \l_uell_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__uell:nn #1#2
  {
    % We need to adjust the width of \uell to be the same as \ell
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_uell_box { $#1\ell$ }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_uell_dim { \box_wd:N \l_uell_box }
    \box_rotate:Nn \l_uell_box { 10 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_uell_dim { (\box_wd:N \l_uell_box - \l_uell_dim) / (-2) }
    \tex_mathord:D {
      \box_move_down:nn { .1ex } {
        \hbox:n {
          \tex_kern:D \l_uell_dim
          \hbox_unpack_drop:N \l_uell_box
          \tex_kern:D \l_uell_dim
        }
      }
    }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\uell{}
  {
    \mathpalette \__uell:nn \scan_stop:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{$\uell$}
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \string\ell  & $jk\ell mn$                  \\
  \string\uell & $jk\uell mn$                 \\
  \string\ell  & $jk\ell_{\ell_{\ell}} mn$    \\
  \string\uell & $jk\uell_{\uell_{\uell}} mn$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathpalette\@uell\relax` uses one token less. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I updated my answer. Maybe we can now save half a nanosecond.

Comment: I had already upvoted it; but saving half a nanosecond might be decisive. `;-)`

Comment: This solution is definitely good enough for me as is, but since you seem to be the sort interested in matters of half-a-nanosecond, I would point out that this solution raises the baseline of `\uell` slightly relative to other characters, as you can see if you place it in context rather than alone on a line. [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhaiz.png).

Comment: @thecommexokid I updated my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks also for indirectly teaching me about the `\string` command, too. I suspect that could come in handy someday.

Comment: For those for which this is not obvious: `\uell` is fragile, so be ready to `\protect` it when using it in headings and the like.

Comment: @equaeghe You don't need to `\protect` it everytime. Just make it robust. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You should still define `\__uell:nn` with two parameters. By the way, also `\@uell` should have two arguments. In both cases, `#2` is not used.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand. Why two arguments?

Comment: @HenriMenke That's what `\mathpalette` expects. The first argument to `\mathpalette` should be a macro with two arguments, the first of which should be a style declaration. With only one argument, you leave a `{\relax}` or `{{}}` atom in the math list.

Comment: @egreg Does it matter, whether `\relax` is put back in the input stream by mathpalette or gobbled by `\@uell`?

Comment: @HenriMenke It can matter.