# Write cursive l letter in chemical formula with chemmacros package

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

How can I replace the letter `l` in `HCl` with `ℓ` so it becomes `HCℓ` when using [`chemmacros`](//ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)? I would like to avoid confusion between `l`, `1` and `I` which look very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
    
    \ch{HC$\ell$}
    \ch{HC$\ell$ + NaOH -> NaC$\ell$ + H2O}\par

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

UPDATE:
Maybe the `\ell` from [stix font package](https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf) is more like you want it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\ch{HC$\ell$}\par
\ch{HC$\ell$ + NaOH -> NaC$\ell$ + H2O}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is a good apporach but there is a slight difference : `$\ell$` gives an italic `ℓ` in the final document while I would the upright one.

Comment: Related: [Typeset an upright ell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175236/5764)

Comment: @ Fizika Scienco see update

Answer (score 3):

First things first: `chemmacros` does not provide chemical formulas. With standard settings it loads the package `chemformula` so lets assume you meant that package.

---

You can tell `chemformula` to use ℓ instead of l. Of course you need a font that has the letter. Compiled with LuaLaTeX this example gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\NewChemCompoundProperty{l}{ℓ}

\begin{document}

\ch{HCl + 1 I2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or like @Roland's suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemformula}
\NewChemCompoundProperty{l}{$\ell$}

\begin{document}

\ch{HCl + 1 I2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

BTW depending on the font the real issue might already be solved by itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
1lI
\end{document}
```

[image]