# How can I renew the macro "\log" (from "log" to "\ell og")?

Tags: fonts, math-operators, displaystyle, renewcommand

How can I renew the macro "\log" (from "log" to "\ell og")?

Default function \log in line 1

I use *renewcommand* for \log:

```
\renewcommand{\log}{\ell\text{og }}
```

That shows in line 2.

But I want to function \log in line 3:

[image]

```
    Default: \hspace{0.5 cm} $\log_M x^N = N \log_M x$ \\
    \renewcommand{\log}{\ell\text{og }}
    That show: $\log_M x^N = N \log_M x$ \\
    \renewcommand{\log}{\ell\text{og}}
    I want: \hspace{0.625 cm} $\log_M\hspace{2 pt}x^N = N \log_M\hspace{2 pt}x$ \\
```

Comment: `\mathop{\ell\mathrm{og}}` but why would you do that??

Comment: Without trying things, in `\text{og }` it looks like you are adding the space you want to remove(?). Also, see [this old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175272/52406).

Comment: People want to typeset all sort of weird things. Generally speaking though, if you submit to journals etc. they would expect the "standard" (i.e. default) styles && the people making the default had researched lots about good typography.

Comment: Thank you every one :D

Comment: Never ever use `\text` for things like this. See what happens if you issue `\itshape` before `That show...`

Comment: Somewhat related: [Typeset an upright ell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175236/typeset-an-upright-ell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard macro `\log` is defined as a "math operator". You first need to undefine the existing macro and then recreate it via, e.g., a `\DeclareMathOperator` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable doc. class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\DeclareMathOperator" macro
\let\log\relax  % first, undefine the existing macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\log}{\ell og} % now, (re)define it

\begin{document}
$\log_M x^N = N \log_M x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Technically true undefine would be `\let\log\undefined`, but that way would be able to "trick" most programs (is it documented behavior?).

Comment: Oh! Thank You :D

Comment: @user202729 Yes, that's used also in other cases. Since `\DeclareMathOperator` relies on `\@ifdefinable`, if the control sequence being defined is either currently undefined or its meaning is `\relax`, then `\@ifdefinable` returns true. This internally uses `\@ifundefined` that's classically based on a `\csname...\endcsname` construction, which yields `\relax` when the control sequence is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to undefining and redefining the command is to declare the log-like operator as a `\mathop` atom.  You would also want to add `\nolimits` so superscripts and subscripts appear to the right, instead of above and below.  This also works for operators that should not use the operator font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\ellog{\mathop{\ell\mathrm{og}}\nolimits}

\pagestyle{empty}  

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \log_M   x^N &= N \log_M   x \\
  \ellog_M x^N &= N \ellog_M x
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

In this case, I avoided redefining `\log` in order to show the old and new output above and below, but you can easily change `\newcommand\ellog` to something like `\DeclareRobustCommand\log`.

Comment: +1. Is there an advantage to running `\newcommand\ellog{\mathop{\ell\mathrm{og}}\nolimits}` instead of `\DeclareMathOperator{\ellog}{\ell og}`?

Comment: @Mico I guess there are two minor ones: you don’t change to the operator font, if that’s undesired, and you don’t need to redefine the command to `\relax` first.

Comment: @Mico This wasn’t intended as criticism of your fine answer, though. Just a different method.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the second advantage is doubtful since `\ellog` hasn't been defined so far. (If it has been defined, then `\newcommand{\ellog}{...}` fails too...)